# How to test assignments to function scope variable in void function?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, jasmine

I've got a function, which I need to be tested because of code coverage.

```typescript
const downloadPdfDataContent = (title: string, url: string): void => {
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.target = title;
  link.href = url;
  link.download = title;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};
```

How can I accomplish to test the assigments to the variable and the document object? I think I will need to use spyOn .. but I do not know exactly how, as the variable only lives in the function scope. I thought about simply returning the variable, but if it's possible id like to prevent that.

Comment: Where does `fileURL` come from? And why you try to `appendChild` a `url` string?

Comment: Should it be `removeChild(link)`?

Comment: Yes! edited second time ... im sorry, kind of tired :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jest.spyOn()` to mock every DOM manipulation.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
export const downloadPdfDataContent = (title: string, url: string): void => {
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.target = title;
  link.href = url;
  link.download = title;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { downloadPdfDataContent } from '.';

describe('67634069', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    const mAnchor = ({
      target: '',
      href: '',
      download: '',
      click: jest.fn(),
    } as unknown) as HTMLAnchorElement;
    const createElementSpy = jest.spyOn(document, 'createElement').mockReturnValueOnce(mAnchor);
    const appendChildSpy = jest.spyOn(document.body, 'appendChild').mockImplementation();
    const removeChildSpy = jest.spyOn(document.body, 'removeChild').mockImplementation();
    URL.revokeObjectURL = jest.fn();
    downloadPdfDataContent('teresa teng', 'example.com');
    expect(createElementSpy).toBeCalledWith('a');
    expect(appendChildSpy).toBeCalledWith(
      expect.objectContaining({
        target: 'teresa teng',
        href: 'example.com',
        download: 'teresa teng',
      })
    );
    expect(mAnchor.click).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(removeChildSpy).toBeCalledWith(
      expect.objectContaining({
        target: 'teresa teng',
        href: 'example.com',
        download: 'teresa teng',
      })
    );
    expect(URL.revokeObjectURL).toBeCalledWith('example.com');
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67634069/index.test.ts (8.691 s)
  67634069
    ✓ should pass (4 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.612 s
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to set up an [onclick handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) for the actual global document as part of your test.

If you introduce something distinctive and testable about your link element (e.g. a unique ID), then you could prove that a click was made on it by checking the click event target is the ID of the transient link.

Additionally you can check that the URL it has aligns with the correct values.

Probably even getting ANY click event would be a legitimate test, assuming this is a unit test.

If the test suite is running in a browser context and you would ideally prevent the navigation, then your event handler can use [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to stop any navigation from actually happening.

Comment: thank you! sadly that will not be possible for me, as I may not parse the elements in the DOM and can not register any additional click handlers. Ill need a way with jest, jasmine and spyOn :/ it would be interesting if its possible to spy on an object via an mock, and then verify by accessing it's properties